# Laravel 9 storage returns 404 on live server

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to show images from my symlink storage directory on my live server (shared) the scripts are working perfectly on my `localhost` but by the time i deployed it the image that was uploaded is not showing and returns page 404 error.

So i run the following command before deploying.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
```

and then run a symbolic link for the storage using a php script

```
symlink('/home/cpanelUsername/project_folder/storage/app/public', '/home/cpanelUsername/public_html/www.domain.com/storage');
```

[image]

My filesystem is set to public as below.

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I have an image uploading and resizing function on my application and everything is storing just fine.

```
$request->file('profile_image')->storeAs('public/profile', $filenametostore);
$request->file('profile_image')->storeAs('public/profile/thumbnail', $smallThumbnail);
                    
 
 $ThumbNail =  'storage/profile/thumbnail/'.$smallThumbnail;
 $this->createThumbnail($ThumbNail, 150, 93);
```

But the image is not loading or showing using below code. any idea why this is happening on live server and completely working fine on my local i also ensured that folder privilege have read and write.

```
 asset('storage/profile/'.$member->profile_image)
```

[image]

Comment: When opening an image what response headers do you see? Does php send a 404 back or does your webserver do that?

Comment: Yes when you open network tab on dev tool the status is 404 for the image

Comment: Yes but what is sending the response (check the headers for `Server`), is it php or apache/nginx? Also can you confirm whether the paths you hardcoded are correct for production in your symlinkcreate.php script?

Comment: Yes the paths on my sumlinkcreate.php is correct for production

Comment: Ok so i got it working by putting FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public on my .env

Comment: you can answer your own question(s) and mark it as solved with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve it by changing FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local to FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public on my .env file